# Facebook SDK - get friends details

Tags: android, facebook

I need to get friends details of the friends selected by the user.

The user can selected his friends using default  facebook friend picker. But when I get the selection as a list of GraphUser I cannot see any details of the users. In particular, I cannot get the usernames.

Here is the Activity of the friend picker:

```
public class FacebookFriendPickerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String IEXTRA_SELECTED_FRIENDS = "selected friends";

private FriendPickerFragment friendPickerFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_frind_picker);

    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragmentToShow = null;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        friendPickerFragment = new FriendPickerFragment(args);
    } else {
        friendPickerFragment = (FriendPickerFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.picker_fragment);
    }
    // Set the listener to handle errors
    friendPickerFragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(PickerFragment<?> fragment, FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(FacebookFriendPickerActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });
    // Set the listener to handle button clicks
    friendPickerFragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new PickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
            List<GraphUser> users = friendPickerFragment.getSelection();
            if (users.size() > 0) {
                ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>(users.size());
                for (GraphUser user : users)
                    usernames.add(user.getUsername());
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putStringArrayListExtra(IEXTRA_SELECTED_FRIENDS, usernames);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            } else {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    fragmentToShow = friendPickerFragment;
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.picker_fragment, fragmentToShow).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    friendPickerFragment.loadData(false);
}
}
```

When I try to read the list of usernames, I always get null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query for friend list with basic_info permission (which is default permission), you only get id and name fields. In order to get username field, you have to add it as an extra field to your friendPickerFragment.

It can simply be done by adding this line of code

```
friendPickerFragment.setExtraFields(Arrays.asList("username"));
```

Check setExtraFields method on related document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/PickerFragment/#setExtraFields)

Comment: Hi 
I added as setExtraFields but not getting values on select